# How did they make the controls in "Fast Like a Fox"?

Tags: input, godot

I am trying to make a basic rhythm game in Godot, but with unique controls. A few years ago, I played a cool game called [Fast Like a Fox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTxA_eJ9PHY). The controls were unique, because you tapped on the back of your device to move your character to move, not on the screen. I thought the controls were cool, and I want to try to replicate them in a simple one-button rhythm game for mobile. Does anyone know if it would be possible for Godot to take that kind of input, either in a built-in function or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They read the accelerometer (and maybe other sensors), which Godot supports through [accelerometer](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_input.html#class-input-method-get-accelerometer), [gravity](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_input.html#class-input-method-get-gravity) and [gyroscope](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_input.html#class-input-method-get-gyroscope). Accelerometers are accurate enough to [read passwords as they're being typed](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/04/android-trojan-steals-keystrokes-using-phone-movements) so you can even get a rough estimate on where the user is tapping, which is used in Fast Like a Fox use case where internally they poll the sensor and raise an event when particular changes happen in one or multiple axes. In *your* case, it might be enough to just treat any sudden changes as an event if you simply care about the user tapping anything.

Try writing an app that will display the delta of each axis measurement then tap your phone around, you'll figure it out. Remember to test on various conditions (device being held upside down while laying on a bed, sitting on a chair, laying on one's side, etc) since different axes will register the changes.

Comment: How small a change should I look for? I don't want any small change in the angle I'm at to mess it up, but the change from a tap is probably very small. Do you have any idea what that number looks like?

Comment: Your idea of small will be different from me. Apps like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrystianvieyra.android.physicstoolboxaccelerometer can help you figure out the values, but I urge you to write your own test app, since Godot may report things differently and in your case the game loop may necessitate different approach.